# Python issue with subclassing and keras

Tags: python, class, inheritance, keras

I'm working with a lab notebook for some open course notes.
One of the exercises is to create a new class, IdentityModel that inherits from tensorflow.keras.Model and has its own method "call(inputs, isidentity=False)". 
It's supposed to be an easy exercise. Here's the code paraphrased, imports copied from their cells.

```
# Import relevant packages
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class IdentityModel(tf.keras.Model):

  # As before, in __init__ we define the Model's layers
  # Since our desired behavior involves the forward pass, this part is unchanged
  def __init__(self, n_output_nodes):
    super(IdentityModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_output_nodes, activation='sigmoid')


  def call(self, inputs, isidentity=False):
    x = self.dense_layer(inputs)
    if isidentity:
      return inputs
    else:
      return x

n_output_nodes = 3
model = IdentityModel(n_output_nodes)
x_input = tf.constant([[1,2.]], shape=(1,2))
```

I'm supposed co call IndentityModel's call method. 
Here's what goes wrong.

```
IdentityModel.call(x_input, False)
```

calls tf.keras.Model.call instead

```
IdentityModel.call(x_input, isidentity=False)
```

has the error TypeError: call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

```
IdentityModel.call(input=x_input, isidentity=False)
```

has the error TypeError: call() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

What's going on here? I've used similar code before without these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Those are instance methods so you need to call it from the instance you generated, not the class

```
n_output_nodes = 3
x_input = tf.constant([[1,2.]], shape=(1,2))

instance = IdentityModel(n_output_nodes)

# Call any of the following
instance.call(x_input)
instance.call(x_input, False)
instance.call(x_input, isidentity=False) 
instance.call(input=x_input, isidentity=False)
```